# Asymptotically periodic potentials

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ho.history-overview, elliptic-pde

Who came up with the idea of solving elliptic equations with periodic potentials and from there solving elliptic equations with asymptotically periodic potentials?

Comment: On my opinion, this question belongs to another site, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If by "solve" you mean "find explicit solutions," then even the simplest examples such as $y''+(\sin x) y=0$ cannot be solved in this sense.